# Efficient File storage algorithm

Tags: algorithm, file-io, storage

We have `n` files `f1...fn` we need to store on disk. Each file `fi` is `si <= B` bytes long, where a page of disk stores `B` bytes. We can store each file entirely on a page, or split it between two consecutive pages. Consecutive files must be stored on the same or consecutive pages. We'll be accessing the files in order and performing a computation on each. Each time we access a new file that is not entirely on the same page as the previous file, we have an overhead of `Tpage` for reading the page into main memory. In addition, if the file `fi` is split between two pages, we have an overhead of `Tsplit * si` for cache misses during the computation. We wish to find an efficient algorithm for storing files in memory that minimizes the total overhead time.

An algorithms for this problem is considered efficient if it runs in time `O(nB)`.

**MY APPROACH:**

It appears to be that of re-arranging files so minimize cache misses. However, the statement says that consecutive files need to be stored in same or consecutive pages. That means we cannot change the order to best fit the available pages. However, since the files are read sequentially, while reading the data we can “look-ahead” to see if the current page that we have read contains the next file or not. Maintaining the index of the starting and ending point of a file might help so that when reading a file, we can check whether or not it contains the next file.

Can someone suggest a dynamic programming algorithm for this problem?

Comment: The fewer overall pages, the fewer cache misses.  So what is the downside to filling each page as much as possible?  And wouldn't you need a mapping from files to page/offsets no matter what?  I don't see what the DP would do for you.

Comment: @ScottHunter: I was (also?) thinking that it must always be optimal to simply fill a page as much as possible *with unsplit files*, since when it comes to deciding what to do with the first file that doesn't fit on the current page, Tpage is incurred regardless of whether we split it or not, and not splitting saves us Tsplit\*si.  BUT: Choosing to split now could reduce the overall number of pages required, meaning it could be a net win.

Answer (score 0):

If you're laying out the files in order, then for each one you need to make a single decision -- new page or not.

There is a trade-off:  Starting a new page will often incur a smaller cost than splitting, but it will leave you with less of the page left over, and that could make future decisions cost more.

The dynamic programming solution is to measure how all possible sequences of these decisions affect this trade-off.

Let MIN_COST(r,i) be the minimum cost of laying out the first i files, while leaving r bytes remaining in the last page used.  MIN_COST(r,i) = infinity if there is no way to lay out the first i files that leaves r bytes remaining.

MIN_COST(r,1) = 0 for r = B-s0, and infinity otherwise

for each i>1, you can calculate all MIN_COST(r,i) from the values for MIN_COST(r, i-1) by simply trying out the 2 possible decisions (new page or not) from all r, all remembering the new minimum cost for each resulting new remainder.

At the end, the cost of the minimum cost layout is lowest of the MIN_COST(r,n).  If you remember the sequence of decisions that produces each cost, then you can get the sequence from the smallest cost and lay out your files accordingly.

The algorithm makes N steps and does at most 2B constant time tests per step, for a total running time of O(NB).